# Node JS radio (audio stream)

Tags: node.js, audio-streaming, internet-radio

Good evening! I just try to do my own internet radio, using Node JS. I saw a lot of questions and tutorials about it, but all of them are old and hard to understand.

```
const fs = require('fs'),
files = fs.readdirSync('./music'), // I have some mp3 in music folder
clips = [],
dhh = fs.createWriteStream('./tracks.mp3'); // create output stream

let stream, currentfile;

files.forEach(file => {
  clips.push(file);
});

// recursive function
const main = () => {
  if (!clips.length) {
    dhh.end('Done');
    return;
  }

  currentfile = './music/' + clips.shift();
  stream = fs.createReadStream(currentfile);

  stream.pipe(dhh, { end: false });

  stream.on('end', function() {
    console.log(currentfile + ' appended');
    main();
  });
};

main();
```

So I have all my mp3 in one single file. What can I do to stream this file to lot of different users, when they are connected. Lot of answers about it advice use BinaryJS, but it was written about 5 years ago. 
I just do not how to start, so I need your help. Thank you!

I tried something like this

```
const http = require('http'),
fs = require('fs'),
filePath = './music/my.mp3',
stat = fs.statSync(filePath);

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  fs.createReadStream(filePath).pipe(response);

  response.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg',
    'Content-Length': stat.size,
  });

}).listen(4000);
```

When user connect to port 4000, music starts playing, but it is not online stuff, when another user connect music also playing from beginning, but I want to do it like online radio. But it doesn't work :(

Comment: https://github.com/illuspas/Node-Media-Server  may b a place to start

Answer (score 0):

I'm also tryin to do the same thing ur doing, and found a very informative blog article [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/online-radio-server-pure-node-js/). There's one just one thing in it, it doesn't explain how to add writables/ consumers to the server, so it is incomplete. But you can create 90% of your radio with the rest. Also I used a different approach so I'd like to share it here to help another soul. ('writable1' is not defined)Feel free to correct the code.

```
const express = require('express'),
    router  = express.Router(),
    fs      = require('fs');
    Throttle = require('throttle'),
    ffprobe = require('ffprobe'),
    ffprobeStatic = require('ffprobe-static');

    // Play all songs from db
    router.get('/', function(req, res){

    const bitRate = ffprobe('myAudio.mp3', { path: ffprobeStatic.path }, function(err, info){
        console.log(info.streams[0].bit_rate);
    });
    const readable = fs.createReadStream('myAudio.mp3');
    const throttle = new Throttle(bitRate / 8);
    const writables = [writable1, writable2, writable3];

    readable.pipe(throttle).on('data', (chunk) => {
           for (const writable of writables) {
           writable.write(chunk);
         }
      });

    });

    module.exports = router;
```